# Symfony2 + Assetic cache buster generating dead links in prod

Tags: php, symfony, caching, assetic, uglifycss

I've been having problems getting the Assetic cache buster up and running on our production server. Symfony2 (2.4) is configured to use the cache buster only when in production. Everything works like a charm on our development machines. On the production server however, Assetic generates filenames like below when dumping assets:

```
/web/js/starapple.min-c875bb6-7df71b9.js
```

And embeds a link looking like:

```
http://starapple.nl/js/starapple.min-c875bb6.js
```

This invalidates all css and js asset links on our production server.
Has anyone encountered this problem in production and if so, what's your solution?

**UPDATE**

The assetic configuration in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - MonologBundle
        - SwiftmailerBundle
        - DoctrineBundle
        - AsseticBundle
        - StarAppleCRMBundle
        - StarAppleCalendarBundle
        - StarAppleChatBundle
        - StarAppleWebBundle
    filters:
        sass: ~
        compass:
            plugins: ['zen-grids']
        less:
            node: /usr/local/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifycss
    assets:
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/responsive.less
            filters:
                - less
                - cssrewrite
            output: css/bootstrap.css
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-affix.js
            output: js/bootstrap.js
```

And enabling the cache buster in config_prod.yml:

```
assetic:
    workers:
        cache_busting: ~
```

Comment: could you please add some more details (dev/prod configuration) to your question?